# Accidentally deleted the /System/Library/Perl folder

Tags: macos, perl

I accidentally deleted all the Perl related folders on my Mac (Yosemite) the one in /System/Library/Perl is the most prominent one. The curl -L http://xrl.us/installperlosx | bash command installs the wrong version of Perl. How should I re-install Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the version of Perl you want/need, I'd recommend you install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) by using the following command

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then you can install any published version of perl. So if you want perl 5.14, you can execute

```
 brew install perl514
```

and then `pin` that version so it won't get updated.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! Also, another way I figured out is to go to another Mac and copy the Perl folder and paste it back onto your mac.